# emacs 26 orgmode on win10 can not find jupyter

Tags: org-mode, ipython, jupyter

I am using emacs26(GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-w64-mingw32)) on win10. I can run jupyter command from shell. but when I run below code:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ipython :session test :results output
print("tester")
#+END_SRC
```

error happen:

```
Searching for program: No such file or directory, jupyter
```

what's wrong with my config?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your config but an obvious question is - what happens when you go to the command line and type `jupyter`?